# CSS grid - two columns on desktop and 1 column on mobile

Tags: css, css-grid

This is what I want to achieve:

On desktop/big screen - 30% of the left side and around 70% of the right side

[image]

On mobile/smaller screens - right side goes on top of the left side

[image]

Here's what I have so far. I have a feeling I'm using the grid in the right or at least I'm not achieving what I have above...

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar content content content";
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #999;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "content"
    "sidebar";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="box content">Content</div>
</div>
```

What's the best approach to this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `flexbox` for this?

Comment: @Roy I was thinking of using flexbox but was ended with grid instead. Thought it might be better in terms of rearranging the area since I want the left side to be at the bottom of two on mobile

Answer (score 2):

You forget to wrap  css  in `.wrapper` class in media query

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar content content content";
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #999;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
     grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 1fr);
      grid-template-areas:
    "content"
    "sidebar";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="box content">Content</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/qsd34p5u/)

Answer (score -1):

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  width: 70%
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "sidebar content content content";
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #999;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "content"
    "sidebar";
}

@media (max-width: 625px) {
  .content {
     width: 100%;
   }
  .sidebar {
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="box content">Content</div>
</div>
```

First i used `flex-wrap` to toggle between row and column as per the width of the screen. Then i used media query to change the width of the elements as you want different widths in row and column view.

Comment: The left side should be at the bottom not at the top unfortunately